# ¿Se puede crear un formulario con un botón?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estaba pensando en que un botón al apretarlo ,te aparezca al costado un formulario o en el centro con Javascript de un documento HTML.
¿Como lo podría hacer?

Comment: La pregunta no muestras ningún esfuerzo de búsqueda/investigación. Favor de seguir las indicaciones de [ask].

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque StackOverflow no es sustituto de Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la forma mas sencilla que se me ocurre es ocultar el formulario, para luego mostrarlo con tu boton.

desde css puedes ocultar tu elemento

```
#oculto{
      visibility : hidden;
    }
```

luego lo muestras manejando este attributo

```
function mostrar(){
      oculto.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

el ejemplo completo quedaría así:

```js
function ocultar(){
      oculto.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function mostrar(){
      oculto.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
#oculto{
  visibility : hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='oculto'>
  <form>
    <input type='text'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
  </form>
  <button onClick="ocultar()">ocultar</button>
</div>
<button onClick="mostrar()">mostrar</button>
```

claro que también puedes crearlo, agregando tu elemento dentro del innerHTML

```
contenedor.innerHTML="<form><input type='text'/><input type='submit'/></form>"
```

```js
function crear(){
    contenedor.innerHTML="<form><input type='text'/><input type='submit'/></form>"
}
```

```html
<div id='contenedor'></div>
<button onclick='crear()'>crear</button>
```

Comment: No es muy optimizada tu respuesta.

Comment: a que te refieres?

Comment: Generar HTML con JavaScript no es recomendado

Comment: por eso la primera opción que le di fue ocultarlo y mostrarlo.

Comment: No digo que tu respuesta sea mala o errónea, porque siempre y cuando llegue al objetivo es válida, sólo que me refiero a que no es recomendado.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz "Generar HTML con JavaScript no es recomendado" ? Así es como funcionan los frameworks SPA, como Angular y React

Comment: se refiere a hacerlo del lado del cliente, por que es de difícil lectura y mantenimiento, ademas de que tiene algunos problemas con el SEO